imageAnalysis.setAnalyzer(Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()) { imageProxy -> Block never fires
I see my camera feed on screen but
imageAnalysis.setAnalyzer(Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()) { imageProxy -> Block
never fires.
            val surfaceTexture = textureView.surfaceTexture?.apply {
                setDefaultBufferSize(previewSize.width, previewSize.height)
            }

            val previewSurface = Surface(surfaceTexture)

            // Set up ImageReader for image analysis
                val imageReader = ImageReader.newInstance(
                previewSize.width,
                previewSize.height,
                ImageFormat.YUV_420_888,
                2 
            )

            val imageReaderSurface = imageReader.surface

            val captureRequestBuilder = camera.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW).apply {
                addTarget(previewSurface)
                addTarget(imageReader.surface) // for image analysis
            }

            val faceDetector = FaceDetection.getClient(
                FaceDetectorOptions.Builder()
                    .setPerformanceMode(FaceDetectorOptions.PERFORMANCE_MODE_FAST)
                    .build()
            )

            val imageAnalysis = ImageAnalysis.Builder()
                .setBackpressureStrategy(ImageAnalysis.STRATEGY_KEEP_ONLY_LATEST)
                .build()



  imageAnalysis.setAnalyzer(Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()) { imageProxy ->

                Log.d("my", "Analyzer is running")
                val mediaImage = imageProxy.image ?: return@setAnalyzer
                val rotationDegrees = 0
                val image = InputImage.fromMediaImage(mediaImage, rotationDegrees)

                faceDetector.process(image)
                    .addOnSuccessListener { faces ->
                        for (face in faces) {

                            Log.e("my", "Face detection")
                            
                        }
                    }
                    .addOnFailureListener { e ->
                        Log.e("my", "Face detection failed", e)
                    }
                    .addOnCompleteListener {
                        imageProxy.close()
                    }
            }


Well the following code did work.
Instead of using imageAnalysis we did check image in imageReader.setOnImageAvailableListener.
Also rotation angle crucial, my android device in portrait mode so rotation angle 0 does not work.
private fun setupCameraPreview(
    context: Context,
    textureView: TextureView,
    previewSize: android.util.Size,
    cameraIdIndex: Int,
    callback: CameraPreviewSizeCallback
) {
    val cameraManager = context.getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE) as CameraManager
    val cameraId = cameraManager.cameraIdList.getOrNull(cameraIdIndex) ?: return

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return
    }

    cameraManager.openCamera(cameraId, object : CameraDevice.StateCallback() {
        @OptIn(ExperimentalGetImage::class)
        override fun onOpened(camera: CameraDevice) {
            currentCameraDevice = camera

            val surfaceTexture = textureView.surfaceTexture?.apply {
                setDefaultBufferSize(previewSize.width, previewSize.height)
            }

            val previewSurface = Surface(surfaceTexture)

            // Set up ImageReader for image analysis
            val imageReader = ImageReader.newInstance(
                previewSize.width,
                previewSize.height,
                ImageFormat.YUV_420_888, // Image format compatible with ML Kit
                2 // Max images to be held by ImageReader at once
            )
            val imageReaderSurface = imageReader.surface

            val captureRequestBuilder = camera.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW).apply {
                addTarget(previewSurface)
                addTarget(imageReader.surface)
            }

            val faceDetector = FaceDetection.getClient(
                FaceDetectorOptions.Builder()
                    .setPerformanceMode(FaceDetectorOptions.PERFORMANCE_MODE_FAST)
                    .build()
            )


            

            val sessionConfig = SessionConfiguration(
                SessionConfiguration.SESSION_REGULAR,
                listOf(
                    OutputConfiguration(previewSurface),
                    OutputConfiguration(imageReaderSurface) // Bind ImageReader surface
                ),
                Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor(),
                object : CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
                    override fun onConfigured(session: CameraCaptureSession) {
                        currentCaptureSession = session
                        session.setRepeatingRequest(captureRequestBuilder.build(), null, null)
                        callback.onPreviewSizeAvailable(previewSize)
                    }

                    override fun onConfigureFailed(session: CameraCaptureSession) {
                        Log.e("my", "Failed to configure camera capture session")
                    }
                }
            )

            camera.createCaptureSession(sessionConfig)


            var lastProcessTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
            val throttleInterval = 1000 // Milliseconds


            imageReader.setOnImageAvailableListener({ reader ->
                val image = reader.acquireLatestImage() ?: return@setOnImageAvailableListener

                val currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
                if (currentTime - lastProcessTime >= throttleInterval) {
                    // Process the image for face detection
                    val mediaImage = image ?: return@setOnImageAvailableListener
                    val rotationDegrees = 270 // Set appropriate rotation
                    val inputImage = InputImage.fromMediaImage(mediaImage, rotationDegrees)

                    Log.d("my", "Loop fire")

                    faceDetector.process(inputImage)
                        .addOnSuccessListener { faces ->
                            for (face in faces) {
                                Log.d("my", "Face detected")
                                // Handle detected faces
                            }
                        }
                        .addOnFailureListener { e ->
                            Log.e("my", "Face detection failed", e)
                        }
                        .addOnCompleteListener {
                            image.close()
                        }

                    lastProcessTime = currentTime
                } else {
                    image.close()
                }
            }, Handler(context.mainLooper))
        }

        override fun onDisconnected(camera: CameraDevice) {
            camera.close()
            currentCameraDevice = null
        }

        override fun onError(camera: CameraDevice, error: Int) {
            camera.close()
            currentCameraDevice = null
        }
    }, Handler(context.mainLooper))
}


Did u attach your imageAnalysis to your preview ? Btw if you are using jetpack compose you should check out CameraX controller and use that instead of your approach. Phlipp Lackner had a video on that.

Could you complete your answer with this link?

but the answer I found  above was working till new version of Kotlin has been installed
